# How to say "At Least" (Adverb)

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I am writing an assignment for my Japanese tutor, and I was asked to list things I can and cannot do. To make things a bit interesting I wanted to write:

> I cannot sing. At least, not well.

How would one write "at least" in Japanese in this context?

Comment: You can use [a dictionary](https://jisho.org/search/at%20least).